# Add overlay in camera application to crop image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The idea is to add a rectangle overlay in the camera application to then crop the image in Flutter. I would like to use a third party library to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_overlay

It will return an xfile after the image is captured.

```
CameraOverlay(
    snapshot.data!.first,
    CardOverlay.byFormat(format),
    (XFile file) => print(file.path),
    info: 'Position your ID card within the rectangle and ensure the image is perfectly readable.',
    label: 'Scanning ID Card');
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement the same thing here. I have my custom overlay, and now I'm trying to crop the image base on my custom overlay, how to do that? I found no logic in the the package you mentioned above, and now I'm still wondering how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: To crop captured image there is another package. https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper